# How to read multiple lines in cpp?

Tags: c++, input

I'm trying to read two lines at a time(eg: This is a line) but for some reason i'm not able to read both the lines at the same time..:( pls help...

```
int main() {
freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
char c, one[100], two[100];
int i = 0, t;

cin>>t;
while(t--) {

    while((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
        one[i++] = c;
    }
    one[i] = '\0';

    i = 0;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
        two[i++] = c;
    }
    two[i] = '\0';
    cout<<one<<endl;
    cout<<two<<endl;
}
```

}

Input: This is first line
       This is second line
Output: This is first line (for each iteration)..please help..:|

Comment: See `std::ifstream` and `std::getline`

Comment: Why are you using `getchar` in C++. Use http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/

Comment: @EdHead i would like to use cin but cin is not able to read lines separated by spaces...:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use std::getline  :

```
int main(){
 char one[100], two[100];
 std::ifstream ifs;
 ifs.open("input.txt", std::ifstream::in);
 ifs.getline(one, 100);
 ifs.getline(two, 100);
 std::cout << one << std::endl;
 std::cout << two << std::endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for you answer....the code you gave works fine when i go it one..but when i iterate i'm not get the output...this is the input i gave

Line 1: qwrtyuipasdfgjkzxcvbnmheol
Line 2: dummy!
Line 3: bfgjklmopqrstuwxzhvnicdyea
Line 4: abcd b efgd hbi!
Line 5: qwrtyuipasdfgjkzxcvbnmheol
Line 6: Dummy!

Comment: finally solved it...i just an additional getchar() after reading the value of t..:)

Answer (score 0):

I has nothing to do with the input but you'll need to reset `i` before reading each line. From the looks of it, you are just appending somewhere in the middle of the first line. Here is how reading one line would look like (obviously, if you read more lines than that you would need to do the same operations, i.e., call a function doing the same logic):

```
{
    size_t i(0);
    for (int tc; i < sizeof(one) && (tc = getchar()) != EOF && tc != '\n'; ++i) {
        one[i] = tc;
    }
    one[i] = 0;
}
```

I also augmented the condition with two addition, necessary conditions, one to avoid a buffer overrun and one to deal with the stream having reached its end. Of course, I wouldn't do anything like this but rather would use

```
std::string one;
if (std::getline(std::cin, one) && std::getline(std::cin, two)) {
    std::cout << "one='" << one << "' two='" << two << "'\n";
}
```

Comment: thank you for reply...i tried your code but still i'm getting a blank line for two..:(..and would you mind telling how to process it using getline..thank you again..:)

Comment: @user2220775: looking at it I noticed that the code was lacking proper zero termination. I have updated the answer. With processing the data I just meant: do whatever you need to do with the input. I have also updated that part to print the content of two strings.

Comment: Kuhl: Thank you for your effort..:)..btw would you mind pointing me towards something that will help me learn the nuances properly..:)